# Rendering happening before data loads - React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to fetch data from my backend api however, my page renders before the data comes in. How do i wait for the data and render the page with the incoming data from the api ?  I am displaying my data on a Mui-datatable. The code below shows my efforts. Thanks in advance.

How can i use the loader to let the page wait for the data before rendering ?

PS: Beginner In React-Redux

**Component**

```
state = {
         indexColumns:{
         name:'',
         phone:'',
    },
        loading: false, // loading activity
         data: '124'
        }

componentDidMount()
 {
    this.getAllPatients();
 }
```

**Fetching Data**

```
 getAllPatients(){
   return this.fetchPatients().then(([response,json]) => {
      if(response.status === 200)
      {
         this.setState({
            indexColumns: Object.values(json.data.patients)
         })
      }
   })
}

fetchPatients(){
   const URL = 'http://domain:8000/api/?data_id='+this.state.data;
   return fetch(URL, {method:'GET',headers:new Headers ({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         })})
   .then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
}
render()
  {
     const data = [this.state.indexColums];
     <MUIDataTable
        title={}                
        data={                     
        data.map(item => {
        return [
        item.name,
         item.phone,
       ]
       }) }
        columns={Object.keys(data[0])}
        options={options}
        onClick={this.fetchSongDetails}             
                            />
       </MuiThemeProvider> 
  }
```

Comment: I don't see you using redux here, how do you store the fetch data in redux and pass it to the component?

Comment: Is the *Fetching Data* part of the same component above?

Comment: No, Fetching Data is not part of the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not stop react from calling the render method of a component that is mounted or to be mounted (unless you don't render it in the first place), however what you can do is that render a loading indicator till the data gets fetched.

at first the loading in the state should be true

```
state = {
    // other state
    loading: true,
}
```

after data is fetched set the loading to false

in the render method of your component

```
render()
  {
     const data = [this.state.indexColums];

     return this.state.loading ? <div>loading</div> :
     <MUIDataTable
        title={}                
        data={                     
        data.map(item => {
        return [
        item.name,
         item.phone,
       ]
       }) }
        columns={Object.keys(data[0])}
        options={options}
        onClick={this.fetchSongDetails}             
                            />
       </MuiThemeProvider> 
  }
```

In fact as i can see you dont need another state, you can start with data null, when data is null render the loader, when data is fetched set data to the fetched data, and when you have data you render the table

Comment: return statement is missing.